# How to write a time skip without indication like "a moment pass" or "a few hours later"

Tags: time-depiction

Here is a short of what been stuck in my head lately

> “CUFFS”, shouts the man as he grows tired of the woman’s protest, using 2 pairs of handcuffs, both of the woman’s wrist fuse with her ankles, putting her in a compromising and undignified position where no woman wants to be in unwillingly. The men reach for the woman’s sizable breast. “Hmmm... demons really do have a body like us”. He gave the breast in his palm a light squeeze and his finger disappeared between the woman’s legs. “It even has the same toy”, he said jokingly.
>
> “Boss, should we really be doing this?”, one of the men asked with a tone of worries in his voice, “I heard those who sleep with demons would be cursed”, he continued.
>
> “Well… Those who want to continue with our demonology session can remain here “Those who are scared, can stand guard outside”, the man claims. “Now, let’s see if there are such things as a curse”.

as you can seen, some really bad things is happening here and I really don't want to get into details, so a time skip seems to be a proper way to advance the scene, but I don't know how to use a time skip without using some time flow indicator.

in visual medium like video game, manga nor anime, we can just show the aftermath or consequences which act like a time skip, can I use the same trick in writing without causing confusion to the reader?

Thanks, also FYI, I'm not really a writer if you can't tell from my writing.

Comment: Just a warning that this may come across as a bit misogynistic - not because of what your characters are doing or saying, but because of the way it is being described by the narrator. Sure, the narrator is not the author, but readers will usually read the narrator's opinions as your opinions, unless you make it clear that the narrator has their own 'personality'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set the scene:**

To make a time gap pass, you need to set the stage for your reader. In visual arts, you can LITERALLY set the stage, but for a book, you need to use words. First, create a cliffhanger moment. There is a clear moment you define exactly what will happen. Then, when you stop the action for your gap, the reader can easily fill in the missing time - sometimes, more effectively than you as a writer ever could. The end of this scene is actually not too bad.

Then, when you resume, you must set a clearly new scene. This will at least need a space or marking to show a change of scene. The new scene must be clearly NOT the old scene, and the environment should change somehow. If one minute they are in a cave, and something horrible is about to happen, then later they are walking back to their car (for example) discussing what happened, it is clear they aren't in the cave any more. The one man may have blood on him that the other decides not to mention.

Having a time break at the end of a chapter is ideal, since a chapter break is a natural point to end one scene and begin another.

There isn't really anything wrong with saying, "Later, after it was finished,..." To make it apparent. If it doesn't look and sound right, use something else.